# Loop over key in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
item_new_name = []

name = [{'item__product_short_code': 'AAA', 'item_quantity': 20}, {'item__product_short_code': 'BBB', 'item_quantity': 10}, {'item__product_short_code': 'CCC', 'item_quantity': 5}]
```

How can I loop over this list such that I get the following result:

```
item_new_name = ["AAA1","AAA2",...,"AAA20","BBB1","BBB2",...,"BBB10","CCC1",..."CCC5"]
```

What I did":

```
for i in so_items:
    print("i",i)
    for k,v in i.items():
        print("v",v)
        for k in range(int(v["item_quantity"])):
            print("k",k)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: It is unclear how the expected output relates to the input

Comment: Please show us what code you have written and what is going wrong.

Comment: the logic can be inferred from the OP input, output, you can use: `[e for d in name for e in (d['item__product_short_code'] + str(i) for i in range(1, d['item_quantity'] + 1))]`

Comment: @kederrac what is `items` here as in `d in items` as this is showing error ?

Comment: @RahulSharma `items` is your initial list of dicts

Comment: @RahulSharma `[e for d in name for e in (d['item__product_short_code'] + str(i) for i in range(1, d['item_quantity'] + 1))]` you can try now

Comment: @kederrac I am getting `name 'name' is not defined`

Comment: @RahulSharma you have to use `name = [{'item__product_short_code': 'AAA', 'item_quantity': 20}, {'item__product_short_code': 'BBB', 'item_quantity': 10}, {'item__product_short_code': 'CCC', 'item_quantity': 5}]` as you mentioned in your question

Comment: @RahulSharma  please post a PROPER [mcve] - I guess that the `so_items` in the last snippet must be the same as `names` in the first one, but it's only a guess and we don't have time to plau guess games. Also, post the full output (what's printed before you get the errorà AND the  full error traceback.  Actually what the error message suggests is that `so_items` is in fact a list of strings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a list comprehension:

```
name = [{'item__product_short_code': 'AAA', 'item_quantity': 20}, {'item__product_short_code': 'BBB', 'item_quantity': 10}, {'item__product_short_code': 'CCC', 'item_quantity': 5}]
item_new_name = [e for d in name for e in (d['item__product_short_code'] + str(i) for i in range(1, d['item_quantity'] + 1))]
```

output:

```
['AAA1',
 'AAA2',
 'AAA3',
 'AAA4',
 'AAA5',
 'AAA6',
 'AAA7',
 'AAA8',
 'AAA9',
 'AAA10',
 'AAA11',
 'AAA12',
 'AAA13',
 'AAA14',
 'AAA15',
 'AAA16',
 'AAA17',
 'AAA18',
 'AAA19',
 'AAA20',
 'BBB1',
 'BBB2',
 'BBB3',
 'BBB4',
 'BBB5',
 'BBB6',
 'BBB7',
 'BBB8',
 'BBB9',
 'BBB10',
 'CCC1',
 'CCC2',
 'CCC3',
 'CCC4',
 'CCC5']
```